# Does it make sense to talk about a Minimum and a Maximum for Boolean variables in C#?

Tags: c#, boolean

Does it make sense to talk about a minimum and maximum for boolean values in C# where by

```
false < true
```

**minimum** of the range is **false** and **maximum** of the range is **true**?

I mention C# specifically because some people mention the C/C++ context, where true/false map out to integers.

To me talking about a minimum and a maximum for boolean values makes no sense.

Comment: Well, often we treat `false` as `0` and `true` as `1` (it may be probability, `0` and `1` for bit set or not), in this case ordering make sence

Comment: Well, `Convert.ToInt32(false) < Convert.ToInt32(true) == true`. However, there's no implicit cast between `bool` and `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Does it make sense to talk about a minimum and maximum for Boolean values in C#?**

Yes, it makes sense. Although C# doesn't let you directly compare `bool` values using relational operators like `<` and `>`, the [System.Boolean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean?view=net-6.0) type implements the IComparable interface, so you can compare `bool` values using the [CompareTo method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.compareto?view=net-6.0). This method considers `false` to be less than `true`:

```
// Is false less than true?
Console.WriteLine(false.CompareTo(true) < 0);   // True

// Is true less than or equal to false?
Console.WriteLine(true.CompareTo(false) <= 0);  // False

// Is true greater than or equal to true?
Console.WriteLine(true.CompareTo(true) >= 0);   // True
```

Therefore:

1. The minimum of a non-empty collection of `bool` values is `false` if any are `false`, and `true` otherwise.
2. The maximum of a non-empty collection of `bool` values is `true` if any are `true`, and `false` otherwise.

This can be demonstrated by using the LINQ Min and Max extension
methods:

```
using System.Linq;

Console.WriteLine(new[] { false, false }.Max());  // False
Console.WriteLine(new[] { false, true }.Min());   // False
Console.WriteLine(new[] { false, true }.Max());   // True
Console.WriteLine(new[] { true, true }.Min());    // True
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not make sense to talk about a minimum and maximum for boolean values in C#.

You will get below

`Compilation error (line 9, col 12): Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'bool'`

[Find Complete Detail about Boolean Type Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/bool)

But in C# if convert false to int then it is 0 and true is 1 but it is not referring any minimum and maximum range. it just representation so 1 always greater than 0.

```
var r = Convert.ToInt32(false) < Convert.ToInt32(true);
      
    Console.Write(r);
```